# Ошибка в консоли "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Есть сайт на WP, разрабатывал его не я. В консоли на некоторых страницах появилась ошибка "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined". После анализа откуда это и из-за чего удалось выяснить, что ошибку дает эта строка `var et = $('.catalog-list__load-more').offset().top;` Класс `.catalog-list__load-more` это кнопка "Загрузить еще" на странице со списком товара, и получается если этой кнопки (соответственно и этого класса) на странице нету, то появляется такая ошибка. Код JS кто-то писал, как я понял для того чтобы получился Infinity Scroll, без нажатия на кнопку. 
Вопрос: как избавиться од данной ошибки. Сделать Infinity Scroll другим способом не предлагать. 
Уточнение: Infinity Scroll работает корректно, и на странице где он есть (`.catalog-list__load-more`) ошибка в консоли отсутствует.
Прилагаю полность код

```js
    var block_show = null;

    function scrollTracking(){
        var wt = $(window).scrollTop();
        var wh = $(window).height();
        var et = $('.catalog-list__load-more').offset().top;
        var eh = $('.catalog-list__load-more').outerHeight();

        if (wt + wh >= et && wt + wh - eh * 2 <= et + (wh - eh)){
            if (block_show == null || block_show == false) {
                //Блок active в области видимости
                $('#ajaxwait').show();
                filterPage++;
                filter( true );
            }
            block_show = true;
        } else {
            if (block_show == null || block_show == true) {
                //Блок active скрыт
            }
            block_show = false;
        }
    }

  $(window).scroll(function () {

    scrollTracking();

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы сами всё правильно написали. Если элемента нет, то и брать поле top не у кого.
Есть несколько способов избавиться от ошибки.

Я предлагаю вам просто обернуть эту строчку в условие которое будет как раз таки проверять, а есть ли на текущей странице та самая кнопка "загрузить ещё" с необходимым классом и, если есть, тогда уже выполнять нужный код.

Навроде:

```
if ($('.catalog-list__load-more')) {
  var et = $('.catalog-list__load-more').offset().top;
}
```

Такие дела. Вам нужно будет самостоятельно определить какой именно код выполнять по условию. Думаю идею вы поняли и дальше справитесь! Удачи :)

Comment: Во-первых, ты в if положил значение, которое всегда истинно. Во-вторых, несколько раз искать элементы по одному и тому же селектору плохо.

Comment: Вот-вот. Так что этот метод отпадает...

Comment: Да, согласен. Конкретно тут условие не верное, но идея рабочая.